# Java to XML Annotation for inheritance

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

I didn't find any similar problem so I have no idea if it is possible or not.

I've couple of classes with the same inheritance. My main class is Material and then I've MaterialTypeA, B, C... All these classes have different attributes.

Until now my main class is like this.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class Material {
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    private String details;
    ...
```

The other classes are like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MaterialTypeA extends Material {
    @XmlElement
    private String propertyA1;
    private String propertyB2;
    ...

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MaterialTypeB extends Material {
    @XmlElement
    private String propertyB1;
    private String propertyB2;
    ...
```

I want to return all my Materials but also with the specific property of each type. So I'm doing something like that:

```
public List<Material> teste() {
    List<Material> materials = business.findAll();
    return materials;
}
```

My result is all the materials but just with the name and id returned. None of the properties that I want are returned. If I change the above method for a specific type of material it works but I would like something more generic. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to annotate all properties with `@XmlElement` not just the `name`. Or use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and then you don't have to annotate the fields (but still make exceptions with the `@XmlTransient` annotation).

Comment: As @icza says, because you have used XmlAccessType.NONE.

Comment: @icza All the fields that I want are annotated. Name, PropertyA1 and PropertyB1. I don't need the other ones. It is why I'm using @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a template for the class containing the "mixed list" of materials:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "StoreType", propOrder = {
    "mataOrMatb"
})
public class StoreType {

@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "mata", type = MaterialA.class),
    @XmlElement(name = "matb", type = MaterialB.class)
})
protected List<Material> mataOrMatb;

public List<Material> getMataOrMatb() {
    if (mataOrMatb == null) {
        mataOrMatb = new ArrayList<Material>();
    }
    return this.mataOrMatb;
}

}
```

You can happily insert MaterialA and MaterialB objects into the list, and marshalling should give you:

```
<store>
  <mata>
    <name>mata</name
    <propertyA1>propa1</propertyA1>
  </mata>
  <matb>
    <name>matb</name>
    <propertyB1>propb1</propertyB1>
  </matb>
  <mata>
    <name>mata1</name>
    <propertyA1>propa1-1</propertyA1>
  </mata>
</store>
```

The context should contain the directory(ies containing the "store" class and Material and its subclasses.

Class Material should start like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(name = "Material", propOrder = {
    "name"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
    MaterialB.class,
    MaterialA.class
})
public class Material {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on the class so by default your fields will not be serialized/deserialized.

Either:

- You have to annotate all properties with `@XmlElement` not just the `name`.
- Or use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` and then you don't have to annotate the fields (but still you can make exceptions with the `@XmlTransient` annotation).

Comment: As I said in the previous comment.

Comment: @icza You aren't addressing the real problem.

Answer (score 2):

By default a JAXB implementation won't pull in a classes subclasses when it is processing the metadata.  You can either include the subclasses when creating the `JAXBContext`, but normally you just leverage the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation in the super class pointing at the subclasses you want to include.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlSeeAlso({MaterialTypeA.class, MaterialTypeB.class})
public abstract class Material {
```

Comment: The @XmlSeeAlso solved the problem but as laune answered first I accepted it as the right answer. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @kneves.vinicius - To be fair, according to the timestamp I answered 4 hours before laune :)

Comment: Hmm, using @XmlSeeAlso may help, but it isn't essential for creating a list composed from objects of various subclasses. This annotation indeed extends the scope for creating the JAXBContext, but if the package path or class list in the JAXBContext.newInstance call already includes those classes, it can be omitted. Not seeing the class containing the list and how the marshaller is created, I can't say what *really* was the cause of the original problem.

Comment: @laune - Depends how you want to handle inheritance. If JAXB is aware of all the classes it will leverage the `xsi:type` attribute to specify the appropriate subtype (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html).  `@XmlElements` is normally used to represent a choice (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-xsd-choice-xmlelements.html). If want an element name as the inheritance indicator (substitution groups), then you can also use `@XmlElementRef`/`@XmlElementRefs` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html).